# Facebook Like button, responsive design, dark/light background

Tags: css, responsive-design

Currently, I have created a site using responsive design so it is viewable on mobile and desktops. I was having trouble with the Facebook like button because the width was larger than the mobile screen but I have fixed that.

The only problem is, on the site for iPad resolutions and higher, the Facebook Like button uses the dark scheme.

On the site for mobile devices, the Facebook Like button needs to use the light scheme.

How do I change this?

The site in question is at http://chinchinapp.com

Comment: I must say that's a pretty bold slogan for a website.

Answer (score 0):

You have minified your CSS so its impossible to see exactly what you are doing, but, it should be as simple as making the image for the facebook button a background image and then using media queries to swap out the image to a lighter one for the mobile dimensions.